# How to speed-up basinhopping global optimization

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I'm working on a program that should perform an optimization roughly 6750 times. Now, the problem is that one optimization has a duration of about 3 minutes. This doesn't seem much at first sight, but if I have to perform it 6750 times, I would be waiting for 2 weeks... Clearly this is not what I want, thus here is my question on how I can improve the speed of the basinhopping global optimization algorithm. I have a feeling that I'm forgetting something here, like another method or some parameters which might help me. Only I can't figure out what...

In short, I have two questions. Is it normal that one optimization can take up to 3 minutes before it converges? How would I go about speeding the optimizations up?

Below a piece of code that shows how I'm currently working. 1750 optimizations are done in the first way, 5000 are done following the second way.

```
minimizer_kwargs = {"method": "L-BFGS-B"}
x0 = [100]
func = lambda x: calculate_score(x)
ret = op.basinhopping(func, x0, stepsize=5, minimizer_kwargs=minimizer_kwargs)
print(ret.x[0])

minimizer_kwargs = {"method": "L-BFGS-B"}
x0 = [100, 100]
func = lambda x: calculate_score(x[0], x[1])
ret = op.basinhopping(func, x0, stepsize=5, minimizer_kwargs=minimizer_kwargs)
print(ret.x[0], ret.x[1])
```

Comment: a few suggestions in likely order of ease: 1) parallelise it across multiple cores/machines, 2) looser initial tolerance on the optimiser and then rerun with tighter on the few you care about, 3) write code to calculate the gradient of `func` and pass it to the optimiser

Comment: Thanks for the help already. However I'm not quite sure what you're saying in point 2. What do you mean with "looser initial tolerance" and "tighter on the few I care about". Also any idea where I can find out how to calculate the gradient of my function, as you mentioned in point 3?

Comment: by "tolerance" I meant the wording scipy uses to define the criteria it uses to determine when to stop (search [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b.html) for `tol`).  if you let it stop when it's "slightly" worse this can save a significant amount of time while not materially affecting results.  as far as calculating the gradient, that would need knowledge of `calculate_score` and some calculus

Comment: (I should note I've not used `basinhopping`, but have written monte-carlo optimisation routines that have run for months of CPU time)